# Javascript inheriting properties and methods from a class?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to make a hangman game that uses the canvas to draw the gallow and the man when a letter is picked wrong. I have built a 'Part' class which contains important properties and methods for drawing the parts. But, for drawing body parts, every line is going to be started on the same x-coordinates. So, I attempted to make a 'BodyPart' constructor which is a child of the Part constructor that keeps the same x-coordinates for each BodyPart. But, when I call the 'draw' method on the body parts, it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
function Part(x,y, diffFromCenter, y2) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.x2 = this.x + diffFromCenter;
    this.y2 = y2;
    this.draw = function() {
        context.beginPath();
        context.lineWidth = 3;
        context.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
        context.lineTo(this.x2, this.y2);
        context.stroke();
    };
}

function BodyPart(y,diffFromCenter,y2) {
    this.x = canvas.width/2;
}

BodyPart.prototype = new Part();

var torso = new BodyPart(50,0,100);
var leftArm = new BodyPart(50,-25,75);
var rightArm = new BodyPart(50,25,75);
var leftLeg = new BodyPart(100,-25,130);
var rightLeg = new BodyPart(100,25,130);
var head = {
    x: canvas.width/2,
    y: 35,
    radius: 15,
    draw: function() {
        context.beginPath();
        context.lineWidth = 3;
        context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        context.stroke();
    }
};

var body = [head, torso, leftArm, rightArm, leftLeg, rightLeg];

for (var i = 0; i < body.length; i++) {
    body[i].draw();
}
```

I have the 'head' as in its own object since it is an arc. I just don't see why the properties and methods from 'Part' aren't being inherited by 'BodyPart'. The for loop draws out the objects.

To access the canvas, I did the following:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Comment: How does it not work? Is the function being called at all? Try dropping a `console.log` into the draw function if you haven't checked.

Comment: What is `context` supposed to be?

Comment: Ok, the `console.log` was called, but it returns `undefined` when I try to print one of the parameters. When I try to print a random string though, it does print that string. Am I calling the constructor wrong or something?

Comment: `context` is the context for the canvas on the HTML code.                 `var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");                        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not calling the `Part` constructor when creating a `BodyPart`. If you change your `BodyPart` to look something like this:

```
function BodyPart(y, diffFromCenter, y2) {
    this.x = canvas.width/2;
    Part.call(this, this.x, y, diffFromCenter, y2);
}
```

then it should work since you're calling `Part` with `this` set as your new `BodyPart`.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1eux64gc/) showing it working correctly.